# hbase connection with java client

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hbase

I have a java program `( eclipse , Maven , windows7)`  to fill `Hbase` which exist on a `VirtualBox` from a service,
the program works fine when I run it from `eclipse`.

But when i created an `executable jar` using the `assembly plugin` in `Maven` and run it from the `cmd` or from `cygwin` I get this error

```
> [2016-05-03 14:46:44,663][DEBUG] Reading reply sessionid:0x154769ed563000a, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 300,4  replyHeader:: 300,3632,-101  request:: '/hbase-unsecure/meta-region-server,F  response:: [2016-05-03 14:46:44,663][DEBUG] hconnection-0x6b63f5ff-0x154769ed563000a, quorum=sandbox:2181, baseZNode=/hbase-unsecure Unable to get data of znode /hbase-unsecure/meta-region-server because node does not exist (not an error) [2016-05-03 14:46:44,663][DEBUG] Looked up meta region location, connection=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry@695e5335; servers = null [2016-05-03 14:46:44,689][DEBUG] Closing scanner id=-1

>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the locations
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:312)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:811)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.fullScan(MetaTableAccessor.java:602)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:366)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:313)
```

Could any of you help me with this?

Comment: Need some more code snippets you are using to guess it correctly. Moreover  eclipse .classspath file entries Vs the classpath entries while executing as standalone jar( like -cp ) needs to be cross checked. Seems like Hbase connection was established. But Scanning the result its throwing exception isnt it?

Comment: thank you for your response @RamPrasadG, i think the problem is that i am using `MapReduce Location plugin` in `eclipse` and when i created the `JAR` i didn't do anything special about this, do you think this is the problem?

Comment: I dont think mapreduce location plugin  is problem. I have executed hbase standalone program many times but I haven't used such kind of plugin. things like hbase-site.xml are there in classpath.. As I said earlier you need to cross check classpath entries as you mentioned that, from eclipse, its working and from standalone jar its not.

Comment: @RamPrasadG do you mean by `cross check classpath entries` if i correctly set the main class in the `jar`?

Comment: please check eclipse .class path file when you successfully ran Vs jar -classpath entries options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some more information like the following may be helpful. Run these commands in the virtualbox where you have the "hbase" command

```
hbase zkCli -server sandbox:2181
```

Once you connect, you can run, in the zkcli prompt:

```
ls /
```

Please paste the output of the above command. The baseZnode of "/hbase-unsecure " does not seem to exist. In general the base znode is "/hbase".

Kindly cross check the classpath of your running program by the java code, as suggested by @RamPrasadG

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.classpath"))
```

Comment: thank you for you answer , i just restarted  the `Hbase` service and everything went fine,   and i have accebted your answer because you gave me the clue :)

Comment: @omar : you gave the statement that "  the program works fine when I run it from eclipse." How its working if hbase zookeeper has this problem ?